# “Failed building wheel for psycopg2-binary” - Mac OS Catalina using virtualenv

Tags: python, django, postgresql, virtualenv, psycopg2

I'm trying to install psycopg2-binary on Mac OS Catalina and Python 3.8. The build fails always when try to install using pip3. Is there any solution for this in Catalina ?

"ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2-binary"

Comment: Have you installed the latest setuptools with pip install —upgrade setuptools

Comment: @bjdduck Yes. All done. There is a fix for Mojave, But, it's not working for Catalina.

Comment: How are you installing it, exactly? When I run `python3 -m pip install psycopg2-binary` (using Python 3.8.0 and pip 19.2.3), it just downloads a pre-built binary; there is no local build involved.

Comment: @TurePålsson I am inside a virtualenv environment. Installing the requirements from req.txt. It was working fine in Mojave. Catalina, Is the issue, I believe.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to compile psycopg2 on OS X 10.15.1 Catalina with `$VENV/bin/pip install psycopg2` after doing a couple of things, first:

- Re-installed xcode command line headers (though it may have just been that I accepted the new terms of service) using `xcode-select --install`
- Linked homebrew ssl headers using `export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"` and `export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"`
- installing with `$VENV/bin/pip install psycopg2` where `VENV` is the directory of my virtual environment

It looks like some others have had successes with just the xcode, but I also needed to add ssl things to the path.

Comment: Installing xcode and linking SSL libraries the way you found, were the 2 steps that I needed, followed by "pipenv install psycopg2"

Answer (score 1):

Try ussing the binary version:

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

If you still have the same issue try using Pipenv instead

and if you still cant install it in pipenv try it with the run command and the binary version:

```
pipenv run pip install psycopg2-binary
```